# Unit tests not importing project modules (Python)

Tags: python, unit-testing, module

My code structure is:

```
+ project
|
+ - - project_code
|   |    __init__.py
|   \    main.py
|
+ - - test
    |   __init__.py
    \   test_main.py
```

In my test_main.py I have:

```
import unittest
from project_code.main import MainClass
```

where MainClass is just a class in main.py

I then navigate to the project directory, and run the following command:

```
python -m unittest discover -v
```

I then get an error saying no module name project_code.main

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: I think you could have a problem with your paths, maybe you'll have to include your project path in your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

Put an empty `__init__.py` in your project folder to make it a package and then either change your code to

```
import unittest
from project.project_code.main import MainClass
```

or do it the relative way with

```
import unittest
from ..project_code.main import MainClass
```

Your `test_main` in package `test`, will not find a module or package named `project_code`, because it expects it to be inside the `test` package.